# In DolphinDB， How to add a new column of DATETIME type that combines time and date

Tags: dolphindb

In DolphinDB， I have a table with a column of DATE type and a column of TIME type, How to add a  new column of DATETIME type that combines time and date.

```
t = table(2020.02.01..2020.02.10 as date, 11:12:55.000..11:12:55.009 as time, 1..10 as num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `concatDateTime` to combine date and time

```
update t set datetime = concatDateTime(date, time)
```